# Need help getting child element using Excel XMLHTTP

Tags: excel

I can successfully get all the 'games' but can't then get the games details using the for each loop. I always get this error

```
object doesn't support this property or method
```

On this line

```
 Debug.Print game.getElementsByClassName("date").innerText
```

Below is my code,

```
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set doc = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://foo.bar"
        .send
        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        .abort
    End With

    Set games = doc.getElementsByClassName("match")
    For Each game In games
        Debug.Print game.getElementsByClassName("date").innerText
    Next game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getElementsByClassName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) is a collection. If you want to refer to an individual item within the collection the minimum that you will have to provide  is an integer for the zero-based index.

```
Debug.Print game.getElementsByClassName("date")(0).innerText
```

That will show the first element with a class of *date* within the **game** element (which is part of a collection itself).

Alternately, cycle through them.

```
for el = 0 to game.getElementsByClassName("date").length - 1
    Debug.Print game.getElementsByClassName("date")(el).innerText
next el
```

The **.Length** is a one-based count so you need to subtract **1** to match the zero-based index.

Comment: Thanks, I had to declare 'Dim game As HTMLDivElement' for it to work though