# how to use getElementbyClassName to extract data from web

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract 78 from Span using `getElementByClassName` but it throws runtime exception 438.

> Error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

I have an Excel sheet which contains group of keywords which needs to search in Google and extract span value and paste it in an another Excel field.

The web I am searching contains 3 occurence of the span where I need to get the 3rd occurance.

```
 <a><span class="xxx">78</span></a>
```

VBA:

```
Sub ff()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim res As Object


lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

    Set res = html.getElementsByClassName("xxx")
    str_text= res(3)
    Cells(i,1=str_text)
  DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)

End Sub
```

Edit:
Even after changing the below line i am getting run time 438 error

```
    Set res = html.getElementByClassName("span")(0).innerText
    For el = 0 To html.getElementsByClassName("span").Length - 1
    Debug.Print html.getElementsByClassName("span")(el).innerText
    Next el
```

Comment: At what line occures the error 438?

Comment: Set res = html.getElementsByTagName("xxx") in this line.

Comment: It is [getElementsByClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) (plural)not getElementByClassName (singular). This should help - [Need help getting child element using Excel XMLHTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854428/need-help-getting-child-element-using-excel-xmlhttp/33854636#33854636)

Comment: I tried and edited my question please do check.

Comment: I did check and you were still using getElementByClassName (singular) which does not exist.

Comment: OK, **span** is not a ClassName, it is a TagName. If you want the third `<span>` element on the page then  `debug.print html.getElementsByTagName("span")(2).innerText`. **xxx** is a ClassName so if you want the third element (any element, not just span) with a class of **xxx** then `debug.print html.getElementsByClassName("xxx")(2).innerText`. You will note that I am using a **2** to get the third instance. These are based on a zero-based index.

Comment: You could at least have provided some test strings to pass in and expected results.